# Getting controller instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap for an IoC project in vs 2012. I created a controller factory with the following codes:

```
  namespace Mvc_Dependency_Test.Controllers
  {
    public class IoCControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
    {
      protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
       {
        return (Controller)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
       }

   }
 }
```

But I get

'Mvc_Dependency_Test.Controllers.IoCControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(System.Type)': 
    no suitable method found to override

each time I attempt to compile. I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264052(v=vs.118).aspx), the method signature for `GetControllerInstance` is:

```
protected internal virtual IController GetControllerInstance(
RequestContext requestContext,
Type controllerType)
```

Since you are passing a different signature, you are effectively trying to override a method which does not exist in `DefaultControllerFactory`, and hence the error. To resolve this, you need to change your method signature to the appropriate one, and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed. I need more on StructureMap as I am a beginner with IoC. Do you know of any howto documentation?

Comment: I am not too familiar with it but this might help:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/135114/Dependency-Injection-with-StructureMap-in-ASP-NET